# Using static methods in Xpages Java elements

Tags: xpages

I have an issue with Java design elements when used in XPages.

Consider the following simple XPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:button value="Go" id="button1"></xp:button>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:importPackage(PACKAGE_NAME_REDACTED);
        TESTStatic.getValue();}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
</xp:view>
```

All it does is put up a simple XPage with a button and a computed field.  The value of the computed field is the result of a call to a static method.

The Java design element code is:

```
package PACKAGE_NAME_REDACTED;

public class TESTStatic {

public static String value;

static {
    System.out.println("Running static initialiser");
    value = "fred";
}

public static String getValue() {
    return value;
}

}
```

The thing I'm having trouble understanding is this.  When the Xpage is called, the static initializer runs and you can see the result in the server console log.  However, if the page is run again, the static initializer does not run again, indicating to me, at least, that the state of the class has persisted - this is borne out by the value of the computed field remaining the same.  It seems that if I leave it a while, the state of the Java class seems to be cleared, and the static initializer runs again.

So, I'm assuming that the class, once loaded, is persistent to a degree.  But we are re-running the Xpage again, so I would expect the previous state of the Java class to be lost.  This does not seem to be the case.

I do not know the persistence characteristics and limits - or even whether it's important to know them.  Can anyone else shed any light on this?

Answer (score 2):

A static variable or class is valid for instance of the current running application and exists as long as the application is not timed out. That's why the constructor is only called once, not everytime a XPage is loaded.

You can "break" f.e. a session scoped managed bean by using static variables, because the static variables are valid for the whole application.